# Magento 2 - Create order using REST API - Third Party Payment Gateway such as Paypal or other 3rd party payment gateway

Tags: magento2, api, payment-methods, rest-api

I need to use the Magento REST API to create an order from an API. In my case, I am trying to implement the payment directly using API to Magento. What I need to do is to create an order by setting the payment method as a Paypal or can say RazorPay or any other 3rd Party Payment method and to perform a guest checkout. Which API(s) should I use to achieve this?